# find ActiveRecord command in Rails does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

In the search function of my application, where a user can input a search text and pick a category (subject) from a dropdown.

In the do_search action in my controller, I find the courses by doing **Subject.find(params[:subject]).courses** where **params[:subject]** is the *s_id* (subject ID) of each Subject ("1234-123", "4123-232", ...).

When running the server, I tried searching but no result is found. I also checked it in the rails console but 0 matches as well.

This is the code for the do_search action in my controller:

```
def do_search
    if params[:subject].blank? && params[:search_text].blank?
      @courses = Course.all
    elsif !params[:subject].blank? && !params[:search_text].blank?
      @courses = Subject.find(params[:subject]).courses.where("UPPER(name) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search_text].upcase}%")
    elsif !params[:subject].blank? 
      @courses = Subject.find(params[:subject]).courses
    else
      @courses = Course.where("UPPER(name) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search_text].upcase}%")
    end
    return @courses
end
```

The schema: courses - subjects: many-to-many

> subjects
>
> > - s_id (the Subject ID): string
> > - name: string
>
> courses
>
> > - code: string
> > - name: string
>
> contains
>
> > - course_id: integer (primary key created by ActiveRecord for each course)
> > - subject_id: integer (primary key created by ActiveRecord for each subject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` looks for the database ID of the record, which I don't think is what you are actually searching by.  I think you actually want to do `Subject.find_by(s_id: params[:subject]).courses`